# Use of Had Been in English Sentence

Tags: meaning

What is the use of *had been* in this sentence:

> We were assured that this **had been** an exception and we had nothing to fear.

I can understand that some event was an exceptional event.

So can I use "was" instated of "had been"? And what did the writer intend by using *had been*?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on this "exception event". Without context, the use of "had been" makes me to presume that the exception happened before those "we" were assured. If you instead choose to use "was", I would feel that those "we" were assured while "exception event" was still going on.

Answer (score 4):

This sentence was likely used in a situation similar to the following:

> Someone is considering taking a cruise but is worried that because of a recent cruise ship accident they are now thinking about cancelling.  The cruise line representative might then tell them that that was an isolated incident and steps have been taken to ensure that things like that won't happen again.
>
> When telling a friend about that conversation they might say, "We were assured that this [the accident] had been an exception and we had nothing to fear [on our trip]."

The use of **had been** ( to mean *true in the past, but not now*) is an attempt to further convey the idea that while the shortcomings that allowed this accident to occur were true in the past, they have now been remedied and are no longer relevant.

Using **was** is also valid and I think lots of people would choose to phrase it that way.  The use of **had been**, in my view, is a slightly more sophisticated usage but not strictly necessary.